# How to prevent cnoremap taking effect for "/" searching?

Tags: key-bindings, command-line, fzf

I have created the following mapping for Ex mode to prevent having to enter `:FZF` capitalized to invoke FZF:

`cnoremap fzf FZF`

The problem is that this key mapping also affects "/" searching, so if I want to search for `/fzf`, then Vim changes the search to `/FZF` (and I have case-sensitive searching enabled).

How can I prevent `cnoremap` from affecting "/" searching?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another solution is to use an abbreviation:

```
cnoreabbrev <expr> fzf (getcmdtype() == ':' && getcmdline() =~ '^fzf$')? 'FZF' : 'fzf'
```

You check that the command line type is `:` and that you only have `fzf` in your command (to avoid messing with e.g `:call fzf#vim#rg(...)`) and if it is the case your replace your command with `FZF` otherwise you keep the original lowercase.

I've been using this for several different commands (for example to replace `:Set` with `:set` because I often do the mistake) and it works quite well.

Comment: Thanks, I guess yours solution is slightly better than Ben's, since it doesn't change `fzf` to `FZF` in the middle of commands

Comment: Just a quick question: why doesn't your abbreviation work, if I swap `cnoreabbrev` with `cnoremap`? In that case, your solution looks like Ben's, but it doesn't work.

Comment: This is because abbreviations change the text of the command line whereas mappings wait for the user to finish typing to define if it's the mapping lhs or not. So when you use the mapping the command line is empty and `getcmdline() =~ '^fzf$'` is always false. To make it work with the mapping you could use `getcmdline() == ''` but I much prefer seeing the command I'm writing so for this use case I go with the abbreviation.

Comment: Thanks. What if I used a `cnoremap` mapping in the middle of a command line? What text is it acting on then? I wouldn’t say that mapping “define”, but rather “determine” if it’s the mapping LHS or not.

Comment: Well it would depend on what you would have written in your command line before triggering the mapping? Or I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use an `expr` mapping:

```
cnoremap <expr> fzf getcmdtype() isnot# ':' ? 'fzf' : 'FZF'
```

You could also (maybe?) use a self-destroying mapping:

```
augroup fzf_mapping
  autocmd!
  autocmd CmdlineEnter : cnoremap fzf FZF
  autocmd CmdlineLeave : cunmap fzf
augroup END
```